# Django field with multiple values and multiple owners

Tags: python, django, list, data-structures, models

I am struggling with the concept with a very join-ed relationship.  I want to have something like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    descriptions = models.Listfield? #or something like this

class Descriptions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    categories = models.Listfield? #or something like this
```

the idea is that categories will have descriptions that you can click that will give you a list of categories with that description, and vice versa.  So if categories were like [Elephant, Truck, Tree] and descriptions were like [Heavy, Trunk], I'd want it set up so Elephant.descriptions = [Heavy, Trunk] and Heavy.categories = [Elephant, Truck]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ManyToManyField` since it's a many to many relationship (one category can be associated with many descriptions and one description can be associated with many categories

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)


class Description(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
```

With this method you only need to add the `ManyToManyField` in one of the models, either Descriptions or Categories.

you then could do the following:

```
new_cat = Category(name = 'cat1')
new_cat.save()
new_desc = Description(name = 'desc1')
new_desc.save()
new_desc.categories.add(new_cat)
```

and they would be associated with each other, with no need for a `ManyToManyField` in the `Category` model

you can then access all the categories associated with `new_desc` with:

```
new_desc.categories.all()
```

or

```
new_cat.description_set.all()
```

for all of the descriptions associated with new_cat.

It will return a QuerySet though, not a list

More info on `ManyToManyField`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Would you recommend that I do this with the categories model as well or just with the descriptions model?

Comment: @Rob If you already tried the code, i had forgotten to save the things and you must save that. I fixed it now

Comment: @Rob if it worked please accept my answer. If it didn't, please give me some information on why and I'll try to help you further

Comment: @Rob When I instantiated Description and Category I assumed you'd have a `CharField` named `name` in them as per your example. If you don't, just remove `name = 'desc1'` and `name = 'cat1'` from the instantiation part. If you do maybe you need to make migrations and migrate? not sure.